# How to sort a list of objects in to a N-ary tree representing subsets & supersets objects using perl?

Tags: list, perl, sorting, subset

I have a list of objects which may or may not be related to each other. Some elements are child items of other elements which in turn may be child of another element. Some may be equal to or totally unrelated to rest of the elements.

For e.g, say the list is {A,B,C,D,E,F} with relations such as A⊂B⊂C, D=E and F≠{A,B,C,D,E,F}. I want to visualize this relationship, perhaps like

```
-> C
   +-B
     +-A
-> D
   |
-> E
-> F
```

I just need some guidance to get started, perhaps there is a module to carry out such tasks. The few ways that I could think of, are getting too complicated & intimidating for my nascent scripting skills. Hope someone could help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several tree modules on CPAN.  [Tree](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tree), [Tree::DAG_Node](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tree%3a%3aDAG_Node) and [Tree::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tree%3a%3aSimple) all look like they can do what you want.

Comment: That was quite useful indeed. I found a pretty [good tutorial](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=153259) on Tree::DAG_Node and was making good progress. But now I am stuck with a n00b problem. Please help me out of this. I have this piece of code which walks up from leaf to root and inserts a new node as per comparison. But I need to break out of the sub-routine as soon as I insert the node, otherwise it gets inserted at every parent all the way till the root (by definition all the children are subset of the parents). I will post the code snippet in the next comment.

Comment: `$root->walk_down({
    callbackback => sub {
        my $node = shift;
 if ($node->name > $compare) {$node->new_daughter->name($compare); last;}            
        }

});`
I don't want to use `exit` or `die` because I have other stuff to do in my code after this. When I use `last`, I get the below error:
_Can't "last" outside a loop block_

Comment: @Benny `last` won't work, that's for loops. I think all you need to do is return false to stop traversal.  The docs for walk_down say "this function must return true or false -- if false, it will block the next step" and the next step is traversing to the daughter nodes.  The docs also say "it's a bad idea to modify the tree from the callback", it suggests noting what needs to be changed in the callback and making them outside.  `my $target; ... sub { my $n = shift; if( $n->name > $compare ) { $target = $n; return; } else { return 1 } };  ... $target->new_daughter->name($compare);`

Comment: Oops, sorry I missed that while reading documentation (or rather read it but didn't know what to do with the information). But even that didn't help my case since document also mentions _"callback returning false blocks traversal below $node, but doesn't block calling callbackback for $node"_. I am using callbackback.

Comment: And yeah, I did read that advise against modifying the tree but at that time I thought that only way to build up my tree (I want to read one line at a time from a flat file, compare it against nodes in the tree and insert it in the appropriate location and loop over rest of the lines in the document in a similar manner). Any better way to do it? (looks like if I can put my tree modification code outside the routine, I can control the first problem as well)

Comment: It turned out to be fairly straightforward to modify the tree outside the callback. When a node insertion condition is met, I just stored the current address to a variable `$location = $node->address` with additional bit of code to ensure that only the address of the node with greatest depth (the leaf) is passed outside the callback. Then I simply executed the node insertion by `$root->address($location)->new_daughter->name($compare)`
@Schwern Thanks for the guidance!